# ios5 - passing data from one app to another app

Tags: ios5

I'm doing iphone application which has two versions Lite and Full.
People who uses lite version has the ability to save images etc.
When they download full version, i want them to access the saved images etc from full version.
Is it possible to pass the data from Lite to Full or version or is it possible for Full version to access data from lite version or some solution.

There is one such [application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/expensetracker-spending-free/id424127169?mt=8) in itunes app store which is working similar to what I'm expecting.